# Solution Representations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have these two individual solutions to this trigonometric function:

> $$\sin(2x)=0$$

The solutions I achieved through calculations are:

> $x= 2\pi k$
>   $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$

The final condensed solution is

> $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}k$

Is this right?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate

Comment: Hint: $\sin x=0 \iff x=k\pi$.

Comment: Your final solution is right, but it would be shorter to write simply $x=k\pi/2$ (shift $k$ by one). However, the two solutions above are correct but incomplete: for odd $n$, $x=n\pi$, which is also a solution, can't be written $2k\pi$ nor $k\pi+\pi/2$. In order to make it complete, add the solutions $x=(2k+1)\pi$. But of course, the condensed form is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given to solve: $$\cos2x=0$$
Write the right hand side as a cosine term: $$\cos2x=\cos(\pi/2)$$
Using one-to-one property: $2x=\pi/2+k*2\pi$ or $2x=-\pi/2+k*2\pi$
This means: $x=\pi/4+k*\pi$ or $x=-\pi/4+k*\pi$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the problem, I confused the trig identity in the original problem

Comment: Well, I have given you the blue print of how to do a cosine equation. Can you do the same for the sine?

Comment: I can it is just I would like to know how I condensed both solutions into one is correct.

Comment: I can do the math, I am just confused because the way I condensed the solutions is not something I normally would do.

Comment: Yes, all of your solutions in your first equation are covered by your second one (for $k$ values 3,7,11,...)